# Is there a way to reset a variable in class and have a function set its value?

Tags: scala, class, object, model-view-controller

So basically I am trying to make a calculator without control flow. I have a calculator class that has the functions which will be called in the Controller (it has all the action classes such as addition, equals etc. that correspond to the button click from GUI). I have three variables: displayvalue, LHS and RHS in the calculator class. The displayvalue is whatever the user inputs with button presses (a function does the math and gets the clicks "1", "2", "3" to be the number 123 and sets it to displayvalue). I want the LHS to be the displayvalue before resetting the displayvalue to 0.0 on addition action. After it is reset, I want RHS to be the new input from the user button clicks. Is there a way to do that? This is what I tried so far (but it doesn't respond to the addition action and keeps increasing the input (eg: I click "1", "2" and "+" and "3", I get 123 as if I never clicked the "+")

```
class AdditionAction(calculator: Calculator) extends EventHandler[ActionEvent] {
  override def handle(event: ActionEvent): Unit = {
    calculator.LHS = calculator.displayValue //store current displayvalue
    calculator.reset() //reset displayvalue
    calculator.setUp("AdditionAction") //try to get the new displayvalue
    calculator.displayValue = calculator.LHS + calculator.RHS //perform addition
  }
}
```

From calculator class:

```
var displayValue = 0.0
var LHS: Double = displayValue
var RHS = 0.0

def setUp(input: String): Unit = {
    this.RHS = this.displayValue
    this.operation = input
  }

  def reset(): Unit ={
    this.displayValue = 0.0
  }

  def displayNumber(): Double = {
    displayValue
  }
```

Comment: `calculator.LHS` and `calculator.RHS` aren't `String`s, are they?

Comment: @KevinAnderson No they're doubles

Comment: If you are doing MVC then the `Calculator` functions should be in the Model, not the Controller. The Controller should send the `ActionEvent` to the Model which updates the state as appropriate and sends update events to the View(s). You should also think about making the calculator state an immutable object and having actions generate a new, updated state, rather than modifying values in-place. `var` is always a danger sign in Scala!

Answer (score 0):

There are two main problems here.

Firstly, your event handler function does not change the value of `displayValue`. 
If you follow the logic of your event handler you will see that `reset` sets `displayValue` to `0.0` and `setUp` copies `displayValue` to `RHS`. So `RHS` is always `0.0` and the calculation just returns the original value of `displayValue` which was copied to `LHS`.

Secondly, you are using `displayValue` to store both the user input and the result. So when the user enters a further digit, your code assumes that `displayValue` is user input and just appends the digit to the number rather than starting a new number.

To avoid the first problem it would be better to store the calculator state in an immutable structure and write methods that generate a new state based on the old. This will make the logic much easier to follow. Having mutable data structures with methods like `reset` and `setUp` makes the logic hard to follow and is a rather non-Scala way of doing things.

To fix the second problem you need to track input and output separately, or track the state of the calculator to know whether the display is input or output.

Comment: By immutable structure do you mean make a list with the LHS as the element?